# Missing libstdc++ in Zentyal

Tags: ubuntu, debian, libstdc++, zentyal

I recently performed a 'routine' update of my Zentyal 3.4 server (3.11.0.24-generic on a i686 system) as follows: in dashboard clicked on the '9 system updates', selected all of them and updated. Now my internet is broken, and I cannot open firefox to reach the dashboard anymore  :'(

It seems the c++ libraries are missing, 'cause when I try to run Firefox from terminal I get

```
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, libraries are missing, right ??

I tried installing them with

```
apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

but I get the same error. Apparently these libraries are also used by apt-get  :o

So, I need to find a way to install these without apt-get, I guess. Any ideas ??

Thanks in advance !!  :)